# I want Unity's slider value to handle large numbers precisely (it only works in the format of "xxx e+X")

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, uislider

I've been using Unity's slider to handle large numbers, and it accepts them. The problem is that the value stored is in the format "xxx e+X" (for instance, 9.999998e+08),
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkcKd.png)
so, if I wanted to subtract one to this value, or add one to it, it doesn't change the value (for instance, the OnValueChanged callback doesn't get called) as it is only sensitive to larger steps (like, for example, changes over 50-100 units/integers and above.

Is there a way to make the slider work with long integers (plain number format)?

Thank you.

---

What I tried:

The slider max value is set to 999999799 (ended in 799). Then it translates into  "9.999998e+08". if I convert this float value (9.999998e+08) to "long", I get 999999800, probably because it doesn't take into account small figures and goes by larger steps.

The only way that occurs to me to get the correct "long" is to convert the "slider max value" to string (string stringValue = _mySlider.value.ToString("F0")) and then get the "long" (long longValue= Convert.ToInt64(stringValue)). This way, I get the expected long (999999799).

However, this is not suitable since I cannot convert this long value into the slider value. If I wanted to subtract one from the long value (longValue--; (999999798)) and then set the slider value to the long value:
_mySlider.value = (float) longValue, the value of the slider doesn't change, it keeps being the same: 9.999998e+08. When translating the number, it yields 999999799 instead of 999999798. (Same happens if I did _mySlider.value--; directly)

I need the slider to handle large numbers too.

Comment: sliders are meant as UI controls, which means they should not be expected to work with ranges much over sensible screen sizes. With values that large, a single step is WAY less than a pixel, you might be using sliders wrong. Maybe you should keep your logic as longs and only use sliders for what they were designed to do

Comment: Imagine (in poker) you want to bet whatever amount of chips you have in your stack, so you can slide from the minimum bet to your whole stack. And, depending on how the player is doing in the tournament, he can stack up a big amount. I don't think an engine slider should change the logic of your gameplay, but the other way around.

Comment: just use 0-1 for the slider and multiply by the amount of chips

Comment: This is why I made this post in the first place: I can't use 0-1 and multiply it by the number of chips because it's not accurate: you multiply the float value of the slider and you get a rounded number. I need the exact number, not a rounded value.

Comment: For instance: 0.999998e+08, will give you a number ending in 800, when in reality it could be 799, or 798, or 797, and so on.

Comment: I doubt a 200px slider will give you 1e-8 accuracy. also multiplying by 1 should not give you rounding errors

Comment: But it does. if a player bets his stack (10,000,000) minus 1 chip (9,999,999), the float-slider (0-1) cannot account for that, because it's not that accurate.

Comment: have you tried upcasting float to (double) before multiplication?

Comment: No, I haven't seen that kind of practice. Would you mind sharing a quick example?

Comment: double value=(double)slider.value; long chips=(long)(value*maxChips); I am not sure this will help but double has a much higher precision and range and can handle big numbers with a lot less rounding errors.

Comment: also, e+08 is just a way of printing numbers (that looses some precision when converting to string), its possible that the value is correct, you are just printing it as float

Comment: That's not it because I'm betting the translated value: I tried with int, long, printing it to string, and those values lost precision. The only value that didn't lose precision was printing it to "ToString("F0")", but that's not a good way to deal with the problem, not to mention that I couldn't translate that string to int/long in this way:
"longValue = Convert.ToInt64(_text.text);"

Comment: don't use strings for anything else then displaying the result to the user. that might be the root of your problem

Comment: I just checked:
      long startValue = 10000000;
        float sliderValue = 1;
        long result = (long)(startValue * sliderValue);
        Debug.Log($"{startValue} -> {result}");

it prints 10000000 -> 10000000, which means there is no rounding error when multiplying by 1. just work in longs

Comment: actually, the error is only 1 when multiplying by 9223372036854775807 (max value of long) so there's plenty of headroom even when using floats

Comment: No, it was just for testing purposes. I don't use strings for anything else, so the problem can't be it.

So you are right, I've been doing some testing and these are the results:
Double, Int, Long (any of these get the correct value.

Let's imagine that the "maxValue" is 20,000,298. On the slider's "onValueChanged" callback, I get the float value of the slider and transform it to either int, double, or long, and all of them get the correct result (20000298). I think my problem has been doing the opposite conversion. I have a minus button and a plus button.

Comment: Let's take the minus button as an example: I subtract 1 from whatever value, in this case: 20000298 - 1 = 20000297.

To do this, I test it in 2 ways:

(1) I get the stored int value and subtract 1: "value--;"
Then I say: "_slider.value = (float)value;"

(2) I subtract the value directly: "_slider.value--;"

In both cases, the result was 20000296 instead of 20000297.

I think this is what is driving me nuts.

Comment: you can't really see a difference between 20000297 and 20000296 on a slider. use it for display only, so store your chip count as long internally, do -- on that, and update the slider just for display (you can use slider.SetValueWithoutNotify() - this will not trigger the event. In your event callback do the multiplication normally, I think you are having issues because you treat your slider as part of your math, which can be avoided completely (use it to get your mulitplication value when its moved, and show the value when it changes, but store your values as long/int)

Comment: That's smart. I think is best to separate the maths from the slider behavior completely. This way, the slider will give you an approximation of the number you're looking for, and then use plus/minus buttons or input fields to get to the exact number you're looking for. I was thinking of using bools to avoid triggering the onValueChanged callback of the slider so as not to get incorrect values. "slider.SetValueWithoutNotify()" seems pretty useful for this matter.

Thank you for helping me through this mess!